# Shouldn't ansible-playbook -e "sudo=no" override sudo: true in my playbook?

Tags: ansible

When I auth with  a non-sudo user I want to override playbook sudo.

```
---
name: test
hosts: foo
sudo: yes
```

If I do:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "sudo=no"
```

It doesn't get properly override, instead I have to remove `sudo: yes` from my playbook. Shouldn't `sudo=no` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` is not a variable; it's a directive. With the `-e` command line parameter you have defined a variable that is called `sudo`, but this is unrelated. It would probably work if you did this in your playbook:

```
sudo: "{{ sudo }}"
```

or maybe

```
sudo: "{{ sudo | default('yes') }}"
```

But if you choose to do any of the above, don't name the variable `sudo`, it will be confusing; name it `must_sudo` or something.

Comment: Oh right yeah it's totally not a var, how silly of me.